# PHP new DateTime get Noon / 12.00 p.m that change every day

Tags: php

i have a problem for getting noon / 12.00 p.m that **change every day**.

let imagine this :

```
$objToday = new DateTime("today", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
$objTomorrow = new DateTime("tomorrow", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));

if (// today time has not been passed 12.00 p.m) {
  // get Today at 12.00 p.m
   echo "$objToday->format("Y-m-d G:i:s")";

}
else {
 // this "else" means the time has passed from 12.00 p.m (today)
 // so, it's automaticly change to (tommorow) at 12.00 p.m
 // get Tomorrow at 12.00 p.m
    echo "what to do here?";
}
```

what methods should be solve this problem?

thanks..

Comment: do you need asia date and time or server date time

Comment: thanks Venkatraman for commenting, i need server date time actually.

Comment: Use getdate() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

```
$info = getdate();
    if ($info['hours'] < 12) {
      // get Today at 12.00 p.m
       echo "$objToday->format("Y-m-d G:i:s")";
    }
    else {
        echo "what to do here?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$date->modify('tomorrow')` then format for 12 noon.